# Tomcat Server in Eclipse: Could not find or load main class db.connection.url=jdbc:mysql:..localhost:port.schema

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

I imported an existing Maven Project into my workspace and added the project to existing Tomcat server in Eclipse. I cleaned and built the project several times, but the server can not start. It shows this error: Could not find or load main class db.connection.url=jdbc:mysql:..localhost:port.schema.

I checked that mysql-connector-java is in .m2/repository folder.
What might be causing this error ?

Comment: which version of tomcat and which version of eclipse?

Comment: @Narsireddy tomcat v8 and eclipse version 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Comment: is it working with external tomcat ?

Comment: I am not sure about what do you mean by external tomcat. Could you please give me more clarifications ? It is working with my colleague with same tomcat v8 in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Define your database connection details in your application.properties file. Also check that your database is up and running and you are able to connect to it through console or any other client.

```
# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/netgloo_blog?useSSL=false

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
```

Comment: The connection details are in server configuration in Arguments tab. I checked connection to db through console and it worked.

Comment: Tomcat server db connection details are same as the one in console? are you able to test this connection in tomcat? as the exception is saying that it's not able to maintain the connection. Also, could you share the whole exception stack trace?